# Zerg research 20 points. Is self heal any good?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am at 20points with zerg research and i need to choose between ships/vehicles that can self heal or special units starting with 100 points and extra energy.

Is self heal any good? How slow is it? do i get more then 1 hp per second?

Comment: I will see if I can find the exact stats in the editor when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, I didn't need extra energy. I never run out of energy as a medic, and that's the energy unit I had used the most up to that point, and Self heal seemed awesome. So that's what I picked. As far as exact numbers, I'm not sure what it is, and which difficulty level are you using?

Comment: hard 10 more to go..

Answer (score 1):

The only things I found really useful are the science vessels, auto refineries and combined reactor+tech.  Since the science vessel heals mechanicals, I went for extra health and energy.

Comment: 2 SCVs is immensely more helpful than auto-refineries

Comment: I disagree, you can harvest remote geysers with auto refinaries and it gives you 3-6 free scvs

Answer (score 0):

In the campaing I did first the missions about the settlers and quickly ramped zerg investigation. Later in the game, some missions require you to attack with limited resources, and having the autohealing meant I could move a heavily damage vehicle out of the front line, wait some time and pull it back in.

Not a deal breaker, but made some things easier than I expected. As for the extra energy, I don't micromanage, so I prefer global automatic features than specific attacks which I may forget to use in the heat of the battle.